# equidistribution in mersenne twister

Tags: random, numbers, generator

I started studying mersenne twister  some days back, it's full name is 623- diamensionally equidistributed uniform pseudo random number generator. What does equidistribution  and unifrom means here? I am confused.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Equidistribution is a property of a sequence. It states that the probability of a number falling within an interval is proportional to the size of the interval.
- Uniformity is a property of a distribution. A distribution is uniform over an interval if its probability of taking any value in the interval is constant.

Comment: Your two bullet points are equivalent to each other.  The terms "equidistributed" and "uniformly distributed" are [interchangeable for sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence).

Comment: @pjs Well, then the name is redundant. I just put down the definitions of each because that is my interpretation of what the OP is asking for.